# store monochrome bitmap image pixel value(0,1) in text file in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap

I am using opencv for reading monochrome bitmap image and saving its pixel value to another text file. According to my knowledge, monochrome bitmap has values 0 and 1 and not between 0 and 255.When I am trying to save the values in text file, then 0 and 255 are getting stored. If I divide the pixel value with 255 then I am getting 0 and 1 but output is not acceptable as it is not forming any character(monochrome bitmap image is scanned text file with characters). 
I think there is a problem with depth, type or number of channels but not able to solve it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "math.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
ofstream fout("monochrome_file.txt");
Mat img=imread("1_mono.bmp",CV_THRESH_BINARY);
uchar val;int x;
 if(img.empty())
{
    cout<<"File Not Opened"<<endl;  
}
for(int i=0;i<img.rows;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<img.cols;j++)
    {

        val=img.at<uchar>(i,j);
        x=(int)val;
                    x=x/255;
                    fout<<x;
    }

}

waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

open monochrome_file.txt in visual studio instead of notepad. The required patterns will be visible.